# $p=n$ in intrinsic semiconductors

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Is there a mathematically rigorous way to show that $n=p$ in intrinsic semiconductors?

I have been asked this question as part of a course assignment. However, everywhere I've searched so far this is considered trivial, and a direct consequence of the fact that a hole is created if only if an electron jumps from the valence band to the conduction band. What could my professor possibly expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key assumption here is that the semiconductor as a whole is electrically neutral. Electrons carry charge $-e$ while the wholes carry charge $+e$ (which is really the charge of the underlying lattice ions.) The net charge is then:
$$Q = ep - en = 0 \Rightarrow n=p.$$

Having said that, I do agree that the statement is somewhat trivial, and asking for a mathematically rigorous proof unnecessairly complicates it.